# How work scrollview inside scrollview?

Tags: android

My Layout structure is like this

```
 <LinearLayout>
        <scrollview>
      <RelativeLayout>
       <scrollview>
          ...
         ...   
       </scrollview>
      </RelativeLayout>
      </scrollview>
      </LinearLayout>
```

But problem is that when we scroll inner scrollview outer scrollview also scrolling due to which I unable to scroll inner scrollview which contains 50 line And able to read only 10 line please anyone guide me,How I can Manage it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Having 2 scrollviews in one view is confusing the OS.

Comment: The answer is already here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490821/scrollview-inside-scrollview, it doesn't make sense to nest scrollviews, because what view would move when you scroll? If you have a horizontal and a vertical scrollview, then you need to override scrollview, like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012545/android-scrollview-inside-a-gallery

Comment: I am open details there are 6 details all are in same size view but when details size big then problem occure and client say do this as iphone in iphone this is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As ListView has inbuilt scroll so this practice will be of same pattern ListView inside ScrollView(not feasible with Android), Then also you can refer **[this](http://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2011/09/19/scrollview-inside-scrollview-scrolling-problem/)**

Answer (score 0):

If I do that for a scrollview inside scrollview it work very well (tested only for scrollview).
I don't know if it's work for a listview.

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

```
if(getFocusedChild() != null) {
          getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
}
```

....