# Why my Android Listview is not scrolling?

Tags: android, xml, listview, scrollview

I have made a xml display with some items . But my listView of that xml is not scrolling. I have made a scrollView and the listView is inside the scrollView , is it a problem ? If I design display with keeping the listView out side the scrollView, then the lisViw is not showing on my android device display. I need such a display where need a scrollView and scrolling listview. My code is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/head_logo" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cardlistButton"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/head_menu04" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cameraButton"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/head_menu02" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/homeButton"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/head_menu03" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/title_detail"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:paddingTop="15dip" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7dip"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="80dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="STATUS :"
                    android:textColor="#666666"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pdtvText1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#666666"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7dip"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="80dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="注文日 :"
                    android:textColor="#666666"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pdtvText2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#666666"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7dip"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="80dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="納品日 :"
                    android:textColor="#666666"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pdtvText3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#666666"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7dip"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="80dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="依頼枚数 :"
                    android:textColor="#666666"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pdtvText4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#666666"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pdtvText41"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#FF0000"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7dip"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="80dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="納品枚数 :"
                    android:textColor="#666666"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pdtvText5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#666666"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/errorLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/subtitle_error"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bluebar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/subtitle_deli"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:text="      "
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageviewproduct"
            android:layout_width="300dip"
            android:layout_height="180dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="11.89" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/productlistall"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

 </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

Comment: its a bad practice to keep listview inside scrollview

Comment: in android listview do not work inside scrollview

Comment: this is a bad practice. even thought if you want to implement then search in Stackoverflow/google. one answer i found usefull here is link http://stackoverflow.com/a/11044386/582571

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Never add ListView,MapView,WebView(its already scrollable) in ScrollView
```

Remove from ScrollView.

Answer (score 2):

**Do not put a ListView inside a ScrollView**.

ListView already handles
scrolling, you're only going to run into trouble.

Using a ListView to make it not scroll is extremely expensive and goes against the whole purpose of ListView. You should NOT do this. Just use a LinearLayout instead.

Answer (score 0):

As samir and coader said, never use them in scrollview; but let this time be an exception, first check whether you've entered enough no. of items inside the list such tat there is enough no. of objects to scroll